# Watch is not firing when v-model changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to trigger a method when a date is changed in my HTML. When I change the date it is updating the model selectedDate on the screen but its like my watch method just isn't seeing the change at all.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <h3>Daily Summary - {{ selectedDate }}</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <p>Change date</p>
    <input type="date" name="date" v-model="selectedDate">
</div>
```

My watch code:

```
data() {
    return{
        selectedDate: null
    }
},

watch: {
    selectedDate: function(){
        console.log('date changed');
    }
},
```

---

Edit: To give more context to the question, I'm running this code inside a template using export like so:

```
<template>  
    <div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3 v-on:click="testEvent(event)">Daily Summary - <span v-if="data.nxt_summary">{{ selectedDate }}</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Change date</p>
        <input type="date" name="date" v-model="selectedDate">
    </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data() {
        return{
            selectedDate: null
        }
    },

    watch: {
        selectedDate: function(){
            console.log('date changed');
        }
    },

}
</script>
```

Comment: I created a simple fiddle with your code, which seems to be working and watcher code is getting executed: http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/ppjtLmxh/

Comment: @saurabh I think it might be because I'm running the code inside a template and exporting it, I will update my question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like `type="date"` fires an `input` event till there's a whole date in the input. If you use the picker it'll fire, but if you update each piece separately it won't fire till the month, day AND year is filled in. https://jsfiddle.net/tg2s4kkq/1/

What I'd do it set `selectedDate` to a default value and mark the field required so the user can't empty it.

https://jsfiddle.net/tg2s4kkq/3/

Comment: yeah I did notice this when in JS fiddle, I think its more to do with exporting the code in a template rather than anything else, I have updated my question to give its full context

Comment: I doubt that makes a difference. Here it is as plain HTML/JS as it gets: https://jsfiddle.net/tg2s4kkq/2/

Comment: You might just want to set a start date instead of `null` that way you'll always have some type of valid date in there so the inputs fire.

Comment: the problem was my webpack was saying it was updating but it wasn't, after starting and stopping webpack it worked fine. What a waste of a few hours. I will accept your answer for the vanilla JS example and the work you put in to help me out.